# Am I supposed to be able to beat the monsters in the capital?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I just finished Final Fantasy XV, but one thing that has been budging me are the encounters in the final chapter: when you arrive to the crown city.

All the monsters, except the troopers, are ridiculously powerful. They will kill me several times before I can down them. I ended up dodging everyone.

Was I *supposed* to be strong enough to kill them? To be fair, I rarely did any sidequests nor grinding, but that did not cause me any issues with story-related encounters ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boss like monsters around Insomnia are **OPTIONAL**, *so no you are not "supposed" to be able to beat them.*

That being said, the underlying question of should you be high enough level to beat them when you arrive is hard to answer. If you just go through the story and avoid most if not all sides quests, then no, you wont be high enough level to tackle them without a great deal of effort.

If you do most or all of the sidequesting before reaching the end of the game, they become manageable, but still difficult.

Realistically, to make them even-ish fights, you need to not only complete most of the side quests, but also make sure to "grind" exp as well. You would need to be around level 70 or 75 to be within a reasonable range of killing ALL of the mobs around Insomnia. Those monsters' levels vary from the 50's to the 80's.

Answer (score -1):

**FACT:**
No, there's no prerequisite to enter the palace wherein defeating the outside boss-like monsters is part. While you will have to fight at some point, you aren't required to fight *all* of the mobs you see in the area.

**OPINION:**
Based on how the story is presented, opting out of fighting serve as a set-piece to evidence the severity of the situation Noctis faces. Opting *to* fight them shows the intensity of Noctis' resolve. Six of one, half a dozen of the other.